# Migrating Azure DevOps Work Items using the DevOps Query ID in the VSTS Sync Migrator Tool's Configuration File

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

**TL;DR;**

- I need to migrate Parent/Child related Work items listed in my "Tree of Work Items" Query
- Is there a Parameter in the Configuration.json file that takes in the Query ID?

Currently I'm using the WiQL Query bit to sort out the work items I need to migrate but I wanted to know if there's a way to tell the tool to get a specific set of work items from a Work Item query, of query type "Tree of Work Items" in order to migrate the child work items under an epic.

Answer (score 0):

I already thought about making a separate Area Path (called "for migration"), move the work items listed by my Query Tree to that area path then have the query bit in the config.json to migrate work items under the area path "for migration", but I just wanted to know if its possible to migrate work items from a query using the Query ID from DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a QueryID. You need to add the text of the query directly into the configuration file. You can use the [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) tp create a flat query and export the text.

Also "Tree of Work Items" queries are not supported. You need to use a flat query!

Comment: Yup! Going to move those work items in a separate area path and use the Wiql editor to generate the text that fetches all of those work items from that new area path.